# fractional type is in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to use rational number type instead of factional type in Haskell (or float/double type in C)

I get below result:

```
8/(3-8/3)=23.999...
8/(3-8/3)/=24
```

I know Data.Ratio. However, it support (+) (-) (*) (/) operation on Data.Ratio:

```
1%3+3%3 == 4 % 3
8/(3-8%3) == 24 % 1
```

I had checked in Racket:

```
(= (/ 8 (- 3 (/ 8 3))) 24)
#t
```

What's correct way to ensure `8/(3-8/3) == 24` in Haskell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an explicit type somewhere in the chain. It will force the entire calculation to be performed with the corrrect type.

```
import Data.Ratio

main = do
    print $ 8/(3-8/3) == 24
    print $ 8/(3-8/3) == (24 :: Rational)
```

Prints

```
False
True
```

Comment: So how about "Rational" in Haskell numeric class hierarchy? Most this kind of picture just miss the Rational type.

Comment: @liuyang1 The pictures normally only show standard prelude types and classes. Rational is not built into the compiler and is not a part of the prelude. It's just a library type. You can define one (or many) like that yourself.

Comment: But I think `Rational` is part of prelude. Run `ghci` only with prelude, `:t (2/3::Rational)`, we get `(2/3::Rational) :: Rational`. And your demo code also pass even without `import Data.Ratio`.

Comment: Hm yes, sorry, my mistake. It's in the prelude. Don't know, then

Comment: `Rational` isn't actually a distinct type; it's an alias for `Ratio Integer`. And since it's a type constructor, not a type class, it won't show up in the class hierarchy.

Comment: @chepner Types usually appear in these class hierarchies in some way or another. [example](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Base-classes.svg/510px-Base-classes.svg.png). There's nothing wrong with including either `Rational` a.k.a. `Ratio Integer` or `Integral a => Ratio a` there. It's not like these pictures need to adhere to some rigid prescribed form.

Answer (score 0):

[Data.Ratio.numerator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html#v:numerator) and [Data.Ratio.denominator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html#v:denominator) return numerator an denominator of the ratio in *reduced form* so it is safe to compare denominator to 1 to check if ratio is an integer.

```
import Data.Ratio

eq :: (Num a, Eq a) => Ratio a -> a -> Bool
eq r i = d == 1 && n == i 
  where
    n = numerator r
    d = denominator r

main = print $ (8/(3-8%3)) `eq` 24
```

Comment: Isn't it `(Num a, Eq a, Ratio a) => a -> a -> Bool`?

Comment: [Ratio](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html#t:Ratio) is a datatype, not a class

Comment: `eq = (==)` would work just as well (given the correct signature).